# Detecting only the last two digits in text entry box for a calculator app

Tags: android, calculator

I'm still pretty new to this, but I'm trying to make a calculator for myself to use at work; similar to a resistor calculator.

I am hope to change a textview and imageview according to the **last two digits** entered into a edittext box. For example, if I were to type in "9,000,0**11**", I would want to display a certain color of image and text that corresponds with "11" and the same color and text for say 1,000,0**11**. Also different for 12, 13, and so on. this way No matter what number I type it only looks at the last two digits. Does anyone know the way to do this or maybe can just point me in the right direction?

here is how I'm

```
private void calculate() {

     number = Double.parseDouble(inputnumber.getText().toString());
     ImageView iv = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.pairimage);


     if (number == 6000001) {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);
        txtnumber.setText("White");
    } else if (number == 6000002) {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
        txtnumber.setText("Red");
    }   

//*and so on, all the way up to 99*

}
```

Comment: All of these answers worked. Wow, I don't know who to give credit. I did end up using Micheal's approach though because it was easy to integrate with the rest of what I had already. Thank you everyone.

Comment: The substring approach would work better if you were dealing with non-integral data (i.e. where you didn't know how many decimals you had). The downside is you need special handling for cases where you have a single-digit value, and String.len() is < 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options. The easiest one is to use the modulus operator like:

```
number = number % 100;
switch (number) {
  case 1:
    // do stuff;
    break;
  case 2:
    // do stuff;
    break;
}
```

For this to work, though, "number" will have to be an integer. It's an integer in your examples, so that may work for you; otherwise you can try some math tricks like:

```
int number2 = (int)(number * 100) % 100;
```

Comment: Of course, int number2 = (int)(number * 100) % 100; is probably not the right approach, since it only works if the number has exactly two decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe convert the number to a String and then look at that e.g.

```
    String theNumber = String.valueOf(number);
    String lastTwoDigits =
       theNumber.substring(theNumber.length() -2, theNumber.length());
```

Then you can have your if statements to read the lastTwoDigits.  Or convert back to int `(Integer.valueOf(lastTwoDigits);` and use a switch statement.  Or put the values 0-99 into a Map and have a Command object or something as the value which gets executed.

Obviously you'll need some validation here on the user input.

Answer (score 3):

If you want just the last two, then I would use

```
String wholeNumber = inputnumber.getText().toString();
int n = Integer.valueOf(wholeNumber.subString(wholeNumber.length()-2, wholeNumber.length()-1);
```

and then a `switch` block:

```
switch(n) {
case 1:
  iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);
  txtnumber.setText("White");
  break;
case 2:
  iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
  txtnumber.setText("Red");
  break;
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go with the sub-string approach. I've found that some number combinations don't multiply/divide well in java.